# Is there a Firefox or Chrome plugin that can crawl/search for keywords from the client

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm looking for a client-only plugin that can search through a site recursively, looking for a search string on the page or within directly linked text files (.txt, .java, .properties, etc...).  The website is an intranet website, so it's restricted (which is why I can't use Google Search).

A lightweight downloadable program would do as well...

Comment: I need to recursively go through links on the SVN page. I don't have access to the unix directory directly.  Essentially, my team isn't a development team, but they need to scan the source code for Compliance and Stability issues.  So the development teams have opened the HTTP interface of their SVN repositories - and now I need a way to "find in files" via this http interface.

Answer (score 1):

I found an addon for FireFox called FoxySpider, which does what you want.

It has a "general" search function which searches for all files of a specific type, and a more "specific" search function.

For the general search: Customize the filetypes you would like to include in the settings panel (firefox addons page).

For the specific search:
Middle-mouse-click on the icon next to the url bar in FireFox you can specify exact filenames.

You can find the add-on here: https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/foxyspider/

Br,
Tim

Comment: Great add-on, but it broken on modern FF. (At least 37) :-(